# Table of points from a smooth function

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a function, say $\sin x$, can I cast this into a table of points with discretely divided values of $x$? Ideally, I would end up with a table of $xy$-values, where $x$ is the running variable and $y$ is the corresponding value of $\sin x$.

Comment: Try `Table[{x,Sin[x]},{x,0,2 Pi, Pi/10}]`...

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {#, Sin[#]} & /@ Subdivide[2 \[Pi], 20];
TableForm[data,
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "sin(x)"}}]
```